# Can't import scikit-learn: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have python 3.7.6 I'm trying to import the following packages:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1ab955ba4021> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      4 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     18 
     19 from . import __version__
---> 20 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     21 
     22 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     26 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 27 from .fixes import np_version
     28 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     29                          assert_all_finite,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     16 import scipy.sparse as sp
     17 import scipy
---> 18 import scipy.stats
     19 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     20 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    382 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    383 
--> 384 from .stats import *
    385 from .distributions import *
    386 from .morestats import *

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    183 import scipy.special as special
    184 from scipy import linalg
--> 185 from . import distributions
    186 from . import mstats_basic
    187 from ._stats_mstats_common import (_find_repeats, linregress, theilslopes,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>
      8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
     11                                     rv_frozen)
     12 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # for root finding for discrete distribution ppf, and max likelihood estimation
---> 25 from scipy import optimize
     26 
     27 # for functions of continuous distributions (e.g. moments, entropy, cdf)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py in <module>
    388 
    389 from .optimize import *
--> 390 from ._minimize import *
    391 from ._root import *
    392 from ._root_scalar import *

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in <module>
     28 from ._trustregion_krylov import _minimize_trust_krylov
     29 from ._trustregion_exact import _minimize_trustregion_exact
---> 30 from ._trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
     31 
     32 # constrained minimization

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 from .minimize_trustregion_constr import _minimize_trustregion_constr
      5 
      6 __all__ = ['_minimize_trustregion_constr']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py in <module>
      2 import time
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
      5 from .._differentiable_functions import VectorFunction
      6 from .._constraints import (

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
     46 import numpy as np
     47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I've tried several suggestions from similar posts (updating anaconda, uninstalling anaconda, uninstalling and reinstalling pandas NumPy scikit-learn, etc, etc) and nothing works. I'm new to python, I would appreciate a simple explanation on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your scikit-learn library was not installed properly. please provide me the installed libraries in your environment for more info, for now you can try below to fix your issue ?.

```
conda install --revision=0
conda install python
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

So, now in process of...
conda update --all

And finally indicate the following...

```
Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

For example:

    $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
```

Comment: This does not look like an answer, but rather more like a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30172405)